# Define a getter without an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, getter

In Javascript if I want a variable to exist in the current scope, I can just do this:

```js
var thing = 4;
```

...and then I can access it like so:

```js
console.log(thing);
```

How can I create a "getter" variable that exists by itself in the current scope, without being a property of an object? Like this:

```js
get thing() {
    return 4;
}
console.log(thing);
```

Doing that just tells me `unexpected identifier thing()`.

This is actually in Node.js, if that's relevant.

Comment: I believe you could add your getter to the global object for this to work - but I doubt that's a good idea. But why not just make it a function which you can call (`console.log(thing());`)

Comment: @NickParsons Because it's for an XML preprocessing tool I use often that does things with eval and I want the least typing possible. If I can't get a global getter to work I'll just do it with functions, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: basically, you can't create a getter that isn't a property of an object.

Comment: @Clonkex I see, you could try and use defineProperty. `Object.defineProperty(global, 'thing', {
  get() {return 4;}
});`

Comment: *without being a property of an object* @NickParsons :p

Comment: @NickParsons Also, I actually didn't realise there was such a thing as a global object. Or I guess I did, but I forgot. Using `Object.defineProperty(global, 'thing', { get: function() {...} });` worked.

Comment: but you wanted to do it *without being a property of an object*

Comment: @JaromandaX oh haha. I think they mean an explicit object they made themselves :P

Comment: All good, wasn't criticising - just pointing out the impossibility of the actual request :p

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks. Unfortunately someone else posted that as the answer first so they'll get the accept, but you'll get the satisfaction of knowing you helped me first :P

Comment: @Clonkex all good, no worries :)

Comment: @JaromandaX Well obviously I didn't know that a) getters must be a property of an object, and b) there was a global object I could use that allows typing the variable name with a preceding object name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **really** want to, you can define a getter on the `global` object (or `window` for browser javascript).

```js
Object.defineProperty(global, "thing", {
    get() {
        return Math.random();
    }
});
```

Comment: *without being a property of an object* :p

Comment: Well it's the `global` object, which mean's that it's accessible simply by typing `thing`, which is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't criticising, just pointing out the impossibility of the original request :p

Comment: Yes I **really** want to haha. It's just a locally-run XML preprocessing script that I want to be as convenient and natural to use as possible, which is why I'm doing things that would normally be considered a bit dodgy.